# Windows Phone Email sent Successfully Message

Tags: windows-phone

How can we know that Email is successfully sent or cancelled in EmailComposeTask in Windows Phone
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can't know it.

```
public void Show()
```

Method Show, doesn't return any values to know if it was successfully. The return void.

Only if you enter on you email and see if they is send.

Comment: is there another way to know this like webservice or any other idea?

Comment: Yes but then you must completely build a real MailApp with API from Outlook, Gmail or Yahooo and integrate it in your App. This will be made with webservice. But in this area I'm not very good, maybe is better to investigate and after post here a another question. Happy Coding! :D